Which package to apply for ordered probit model (Polr or Odinal)?
I am developing an ordered probit model. I am curious about which package to apply. I am looking into the polr function from the MASS package and the clm function from the ordinal package in R. The coefficient level of output from both models can be interpretable considering my research objective.
I wonder how a researcher decides which package to use.

I believe they will give similar if not identical results, but the ordinal package supports a wider range of models, including mixed effects models.
